# SSIS Load MySQL query into a SSIS temp table

Tags: ssis

I am trying to load the results from a MySQL query into a SQL Server temporary table using SSIS and can't figure this out.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Mark

[Ado Destination editor screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZNa1.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far? What issues are you encountering?

Comment: Just trying to help you ask better questions on SO. Remove your comment and update your question with the new information. Include the DDL you used to create the SQL table and a screenshot of the Data Flow Task in SSIS.

Comment: Chris, writing a response to your questions made me think logically about the problem and I was able to come up with a solution. One of my problems is I had to put quotes around the temporary table name on the ADO.NET Destination editor screen. Thanks for your help. You made me think. Mark